# Grouping datetime fields into chunks

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a mysql MyIsam table with a field datestamp (datetime), I am trying to return all records that have a datestamp within the last 3 hours, but group it into 10 chunks (so for this example group one would be the first 18 minutes etc...)

Any ideas? Is this possible in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may work:

```
$t = date("U",strtotime("-3 Hours"));
$sql = "SELECT *, FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datestamp) - ".$t.") / 1080) as chunk 
    FROM table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datestamp) > '".$t."' GROUP BY chunk";
```

Devide the difference with 1/10th of the 3 hour interval (1080 sec). This gives chunks 0,1,2...9, where 0 means the first 18 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. As I'm not really a MySQL expert, this is pseudocode:

```
SELECT ..., (now() - datestamp) AS age, age / 600 AS group, ...
```

Then you have two columns, "age" that you use to limit the selection, and "group" that further subdivides.

Answer (score 0):

use like

```
   SELECT SUM(myfields)..... FROM mytable  
    WHERE mydate >= DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 3 HOUR) 
    GROUP BY FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mydate) ) / 10800)
```

10800 is the number of second in 3 hours